# Find all the solutions of $e^z=i$

Tags: complex-numbers

Find all the solutions of $e^z=i$

I don't know where to start.

I want to do $z=\ln(i)$, but have no idea where that would lead me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: write $z=x+iy$ and solve the real and imaginary parts separately: $$e^{x+iy} = e^x (\cos y + i \sin y) = 0 + i$$

---

Adding more detail:

$$\begin{cases}e^x \cos y = 0 \\ e^x \sin y = 1\end{cases}$$
Noting that $e^x > 0$ for any $x$,
$$e^x \cos y = 0 \implies \cos y = 0 \implies y = \pi/2 + k \implies \sin y = \pm 1$$
Again, using the fact that $e^x>0$, this implies
$$\sin y = 1 \implies \begin{cases}x=0 \\ y=\pi/2 + 2\pi k\end{cases}$$

Comment: Okay, I've got that. But now what do I need to do? Take natural logs to both sides? $\cos y+i\sin y=\ln(i)$.

Answer (score 3):

As $\displaystyle i=\cos\frac\pi2+i\sin\frac\pi2$

using [Euler formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html) $\displaystyle i=e^{i\frac\pi2}=e^{i\left(2m\pi+\frac\pi2\right)}$ where $m$ is any integer

Comment: How does $i=\cos \frac{\pi}{2} + i\sin \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: @MrCroutini, what are the values of $\cos\frac\pi2,\sin\frac\pi2$?  To derive the relation we can set $0=r\sin\psi, 1=r\cos\psi$ where $r>0$

Comment: $\cos \frac{\pi}{2}=0$ and $\sin \frac{\pi}{2}=1$. Okay, I understand that, thanks.

Comment: I understand everything, apart from the last equality. Could you explain it? Is it because $\sin(x)$ is $2\pi$ periodic?

Comment: @MrCroutini, right. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3861/what-is-your-favorite-proof-that-eix-has-a-period-of-2-pi

Answer (score -2):

Write $i$ as ${\large e^{i\left(\dfrac\pi2 + 2n\pi\right)}}$. Then compare the powers on both sides, take LCM and boom!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).